# I'm getting request failed error and axios error 403

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an error 403 with my code whenever I enter data in the API. I was following a sequence of videos for this Computer Aided Learning app that I am trying to develop  and I've searched a lot of ways to fix it. the API got no problem accepting data before after implementing new changes it got this error.

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const baseUrl='http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/teacher/';
    
function TeacherRegister(){
        const [teacherData, setteacherData]=useState({
            'full_name':'',
            'email':'',
            'password':'',
            'mobile_no':'',
            'skills':'',
            'status':''
        });
        //Change element value
        const handleChange=(event)=>{
            setteacherData({
                ...teacherData,
                [event.target.name]:event.target.value
            });
        }
        //Submit Form
        const submitForm=()=>{
            const teacherFormData=new FormData();
            teacherFormData.append("full_name", teacherData.full_name)
            teacherFormData.append("email", teacherData.email)
            teacherFormData.append("password", teacherData.password)
            teacherFormData.append("mobile_no", teacherData.mobile_no)
            teacherFormData.append("skills", teacherData.skills)
    
            try{
                axios.post(baseUrl,teacherFormData).then((response)=>{
                    setteacherData({
                        'full_name':'',
                        'email':'',
                        'password':'',
                        'mobile_no':'',
                        'skills':'',
                        'status':'success'
    
                    });
                });
            }catch(error){
                console.log(error);
                setteacherData({'status':'error'})
            }
        };
            
        //end Submit
    
        useEffect(()=>{
            document.title='Teacher Register';
        });
    
        return(
            <div className="container mt-4">
                <div className="row"> 
                <div className="col-6 offset-3">
    
                {teacherData.status=='success' && <p class="text-success">Thanks for your registration!</p>}
                    {teacherData.status=='error' && <p class="text-danger">Something wrong happened!</p>}
    
                    <div className="card">
                        <h5 className="card-header">Teacher Register</h5>
                        <div className="card-body">
                        <form>
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <label htmlFor="full_name" className="form-label">Full Name</label>
                                <input value={teacherData.full_name} onChange={handleChange} type="text" className="form-control" name="full_name" aria-describedby="emailHelp"/>                            
                            </div>
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">Email</label>
                                <input value={teacherData.email} onChange={handleChange} type="email" className="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp"/>                            
                            </div>
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">Password</label>
                                <input value={teacherData.password} onChange={handleChange} type="password" className="form-control" name="password"/>
                            </div>                        
                            {/* <div className="mb-3 form-check">
                                <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1"/>
                                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="exampleCheck1">Remember Me</label>
                            </div> */}
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <label htmlFor="mobile_no" className="form-label">Mobile Number</label>
                                <input value={teacherData.mobile_no} onChange={handleChange} type="number" className="form-control" name="mobile_no"/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <label htmlFor="skills" className="form-label">Skills</label>
                                <textarea value={teacherData.skills} onChange={handleChange} name="skills" className="form-control"></textarea>                            
                            </div>
                            <button onClick={submitForm} type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                            </form>
    
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default TeacherRegister;
```

Comment: 403 is issued by the server when the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it. client code is all well and good, but  it's the server code that you need to debug

Answer (score 0):

403 error typically indicates that you are trying to access a resource (in this case, an API) for which you do not have permission.
Make sure that your API server is properly configured to accept POST requests from your frontend application at the specified URL  http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/teacher/